# Is there an equivalent of PyMongo for Python 3.2?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x

I attempted to install **pymongo** to my Windows box with Python 3.2 through **easy_install**, only to find that it will not install due to incompatibilities with Python 3.2.

Therefore, is there an equivalent to pymongo that will work with Python 3.2? MongoDB is an integral part of the application I was developing on Python 2.7, and to move to Python 3.2 I will need to retain this interactivity.

Thanks!

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo3

Comment: Derp. Thanks, should I close the question now?

Comment: May as well leave it. That project is currently described as "unofficial", so this subject might require revisiting at a later date. Best of luck with your app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit: this answer is outdated. PyMongo now officially supports Python 3.**

---

The answer was already given in comments, but I'll provide a comprehensive summary nontheless:

- As of May 2011, Python 3 is not officially supported by MongoDB
- Ticket for "Support for Python 3" has been some years ago (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-84) so the MongoDB developers are aware of this need.
- As already told by Adam, there is a port of PyMongo for Python 3 in PyPi (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo3) which could be used and is defined as "semi-official"
- Source codes for the Python 3 fork are available at https://github.com/sovnarkom/mongo-python3-driver
- If you want make on impact on making this fork official make an upvote to its ticket (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-84)
- With enough upvotes/user requests, I would expect to get an official Python 3 driver someday

Comment: As of 20121105 this is still the accepted answer, but as another answer indicates: since version 2.2 PyMongo officially support Python3

Comment: Thanks for the update. Added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with the 2.2 release PyMongo supports python 3.x where x >= 1.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo

Answer (score 0):

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/python3.html

Via freenode and #web.