# Unable to install pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x

I am unable to install pymongo using easy_install on python 3.2.

```
    c:\Python32\Scripts>easy_install pymongo
...
    Processing pymongo-2.0.1.tar.gz
    Running pymongo-2.0.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\rajesh\appdata\l
    ocal\temp\easy_install-dflvnv\pymongo-2.0.1\egg-dist-tmp-m35zko
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Python32\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", lin
    e 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.21', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
      File "c:\Python32\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.21-
    py3.2.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1876, in main
        with_ei_usage(lambda:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official PyMongo for Python 3.

[Is there an equivalent of PyMongo for Python 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360715/is-there-an-equivalent-of-pymongo-for-python-3-2)

As noted there though, there is a semi official port, available on PyPI as pymongo3: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo3

Comment: Support for python >= 3.1 was added in [version 2.2 of pymongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/a799d5276549e70826dd856315233275a8c5986f/doc/changelog.rst#changes-in-version-22)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
easy_install pymongo3
```